# Do I need a visa for Singapore if I have an Australian PR?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, singapore, australian-residents

Planning to travel from Melbourne to Mumbai via Singapore and take a long stopover of over 10hrs (mostly 18hrs).

I'm an Indian national with Australian PR.  I'm a bit confused if I need to apply for a visa or I will be eligible for the **Visa Free Transit Facility**.

This link says I can get Visa Free Transit Facility:
https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf

But this link says I need to apply for a visa:
http://www.vfsglobal.com/singapore/australia/faqs.html

**Question:** Do I need to apply for a visa or can I get one at Singapore airport?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a single ticket connecting through Singapore, **you are eligible for VFTF and do not need a Singaporean visa.**

ICA is the official site of Singapore Immigration and is authoritative here.  VFS is a commercial visa service and their page doesn't directly contradict the ICA site, they just don't mention the VFTF at all.

Obligatory note: you're not guaranteed to be granted the VFTF, but the worst case scenario is that you spend 10 hours on the airside at Changi.  Having an easily explainable plan for what you're going to do in Sg for ten hours would be helpful.

Comment: yes I have a single ticket  .... "you're not guaranteed to be granted" - does this happen often ?

Comment: @NigelFds No, but it's less safe than receiving a visa in advance (which is also not 100% guaranteed, but close to it).

Comment: @NigelFds If you didn't previously have trouble with Singapore immigration, such as being refused entry, then it's unlikely you'll have any problem.

Comment: But note - it's no punishment to be stuck on Changi Airport for 10 hours. There are plenty things to do airside.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've been to a couple of countries before, never had any issue